# redirect directories to a file with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all users who are trying to access address like this:

> http://www.example.com/AnyName

to

> http://www.example.com/images/managers/AnyName.jpg

Comment: `http://www.example.com/AnyName`  or `http://www.example.com/AnyName.jpg`

Comment: http://www.example.com/AnyName is better but http://www.example.com/AnyName.jpg is acceptable too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^http://(www\.)?example.com
RewriteRule  ^([^\/]+\.jpg)$  /images/managers/$1  [L]
```

Comment: there are two problems: first, the webpages that contains jpg files, cannot load them (I think we need to change it so that only hot-linked files get redirected). second, when i tried http://www.example.com/filename.jpg, I get internal server error code 500

Comment: I edited my answer. Now rewrite rule works only if request has no referrer or has your site as referrer!